# Please merge svn and subversion tags (again)

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Is it time to merge svn and subversion tags again? Below are tag counts for both tags on the trilogy sites.

<strike>Stack Overflow:</strike>

- [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn) 4523
- [subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subversion) 9

<strike>Server Fault:</strike>

- [svn](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/svn) 260
- [subversion](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/subversion) 161

<strike>Super User:</strike>

- [svn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/svn) 100
- [subversion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/subversion) 0

Comment: Or just implement tag synonyms and make the two mean the same thing.

Comment: @jjnguy:  Agreed.  Those who like that idea should upvote this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms

Comment: It's the request that keeps on requesting.

Comment: @jjinguy: I think synonyms are a bad idea, but automatic re-naming at edit/creation time would be better.

Comment: Could someone please do it on Server Fault too?

Comment: I updated tag counts. Time for new tag merge?

Comment: done on SU: 2010-04-02

Comment: Updated tag counts. Server Fault still has a significant number of svn and subversion tags.

Answer (score 4):

<del>Done on stackoverflow, plus a tag dedup.</del>

<del>And again...</del> <sub><del>(Dec 7 at 9:52)</del></sub>

And again...<sub>(Apr 23)</sub>

<sub>Waiting for another *And again...* <sub>*And again...*<sub>*And again...*<sub>*And again...*<sub>*And again...*<sub>*And again...*</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

Jeff, when is this black list up and running?

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: @Pol, it's interesting that http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms now stands strong at 68 upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I did the ones on SO by hand.

Since there were only 9 questions, next time you can take care of them yourself since you have enough rep. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38987/how-many-retags-should-you-do-before-asking-a-moderator) for guidelines on when to retag and when to ask for help. I don't mean to be snarky, but for a really trivial number of questions, the mods don't need to be called in and do extra work that we as a community can accomplish in seconds. We have the power, we should use it.

The merge on SF, on the other hand, *should* be done by the mod's automagic non-bumping merge process since there are quite a few that need retagging.

Comment: Doing that many retags manually is annoying because captcha kicks in all the time.

Comment: @Juha: After a while, you get used to it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/captcha

Answer (score 1):

Merged on Serverfault as well.